Read JSON in Pug NodeJs
I am sending a variable in the rendering response of my index view on my website, this variable is a JSON, but I cannot read it in Pug.
JSON:
 {
   "expirepass": false,
   "memberships": {
    "view": 0,
    "create": 0,
    "edit": 0,
    "authorize": 0,
    "print": 0,
    "delete": 0
   },
   "forms": {
    "view": 1,
    "create": 0,
    "edit": 0,
    "authorize": 0,
    "execute": 0,
    "delete": 0
   },
   "users": {
    "view": 0,
    "create": 0,
    "edit": 0,
    "delete": 0
   }
 }

index.js:
 //req.session.settings is the string that I save with the JSON
 let data = JSON.parse(req.session.settings); 
 //I print through the console to verify (positive result)
 console.log(data,data.forms,data.forms.view); 
 res.render('index',{data:data});

index.pug:
 p= data.forms

Result in view:
https://i.sstatic.net/qT8Hu.png
Is there any way or way to access this JSON in Pug?

I'm pretty sure setting the contents of an element will automatically coerce it to a string. You can try doing p= JSON.stringify(data.forms), but usually you would want to actually use the data

@grimsteel Yes, the idea is to be able to validate if the user has permissions to view ('view') etc., I would like to be able to use them in a condition similar to this: if data.forms.view and then grant the permission

It is working as expected. The rendered output [object Object] is because data.forms is an object and not a simple value. Try something like p=data.forms.view.
